# Comparing strings with == gives wrong ? result

Tags: python, logic

I'm trying to compare two strings e.g. `if self.Ends == '101100' or '001101'` .  `self.Ends` is in a class to compare two 3D co-ordinates. it may hold `000100`.  There are eight `if` `elif` comparisons.

The program always returns  an `'a'` even `self.Ends` holds another 01 string.

```
if self.Ends == '100101' or '101100':
     P_line.Line = 'a'   

elif self.Ends == '000100' or '100000':
     P_line.Line = 'b'
```

Comment: `'101100'` is a non-zero-length string and as such is always true. So is `'100000'`. Therefore both your `if` statements are always true.

Comment: Ordinarily I'm a big fan of language constructs that read like English, but this one trips up far too many people.

Answer (score 5):

You need to compare the string to `self.Ends` on both sides of the `or`. Otherwise it will always be true. ie. `if 1:` is the same as `if 'a':` They will both evaluate to `True`

```
  if self.Ends == '100101' or self.Ends == '101100':
         P_line.Line = 'a'   

   elif self.Ends == '000100' or self.Ends == '100000':
         P_line.Line = 'b'
```

Comment: Can also use `if self.Ends in ('100101', '101100'):`

Comment: Yes, that is a more pythonic way for sure.

Answer (score 1):

@jramirez answered the *why*, but this is an alternative approach to begin with.

This might be better than making all of those `if`, `elif`, `else`

```
>>> mapper = {'a': ('100101', '101100'), 'b': ('000100', '100000')}
>>> def get_line(bits, default='default'):
...     for k, v in mapper.items():
...         if bits in v:
...             return k
...     return default
...
>>> get_line('100101')
'a'
>>> get_line('000100')
'b'
>>> get_line('1', 'z')
'z'
```

So your code would look like

```
P_line.Line = get_line(self.Ends)
```

or with an optional default

```
P_line.Line = get_line(self.Ends, 'z')
```